# How to write a list of maps in DDB via AWS/DDB Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

Say currently I have a DDB that looks like this:

```
EMP_DATA {
  empName: String,
  empId: Number
}
```

Now, I want to add a new `List` field to this table called `iceCreamFlavorsTried`. An employee can have tried multiple ice cream flavors. The schema of this field will look like this:

```
iceCreamFlavorsTried {
  [
  flavor: String,
  rating: Number,
  lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: Long, //Long represents Millis timestamp
  outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: Number
  ]
}
```

So, I kind of want the schema to look like:

```
EMP_DATA {
  empName: String,
  empId: Number,
  iceCreamFlavorsTried: List
}
```

Things my Java code will need to do via AWS/DDB SDK are:

1. Each time an employee tries a new ice cream flavor, they should be able to add that flavor to the `iceCreamFlavorsTried` list associated to their employee record in the DDB table.
2. Every time an employee tries a flavor they have already previously tried (hence this flavor already exists in the `iceCreamFlavorsTried` list for that employee's record in the DDB table), the code needs to update that item in the list (instead of creating a new item in the list).

For example, suppose at t=1692204729004, Mike (`empId: 1234`) has tried his very first flavor of ice cream, which is `{flavor: "Double Chocolate", rating: 8.5, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204729004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 64}`. This means his record in EMP_DATA should look like:

```
{empName: "Mike", empId: 1234, iceCreamFlavorsTried: [{flavor: "Double Chocolate", rating: 8.5, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204729004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 64}]}
```

Now, at t=1692204739004, he tries a new flavor. He tried the Strawberry flavor. He rated it 9.5 and it was 80 degrees when he tried it. Now, his record in the EMP_DATA table should look like:

```
{empName: "Mike", empId: 1234, iceCreamFlavorsTried: [{flavor: "Double Chocolate", rating: 8.5, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204729004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 64}, {flavor: "Strawberry", rating: 9.5, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204739004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 80}]}
```

Finally, at t=1692204749004, he tries the Double Chocolate flavor again. He rated it a 9.1 and it was 97 degrees when he tried it. Now, his record in the EMP_DATA table should look like (notice how the `iceCreamFlavorsTried` list still only has two items in it, with one of them simply being updated - the Double Chocolate item was updated to reflect the new rating, time flavor was last tried, and the temperature when flavor was last tried):

```
{empName: "Mike", empId: 1234, iceCreamFlavorsTried: [{flavor: "Double Chocolate", rating: 9.1, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204749004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 97}, {flavor: "Strawberry", rating: 9.5, lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried: 1692204739004, outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried: 80}]}
```

I want to understand how to most simply do this write/update to a DDB table via the DDB/AWS Java SDK. Assume I already have access to a DDB client `AmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient`. I want to understand how to write this new `IceCreamFlavorsTried: List` field to my existing table. Which operations of this client should I use? How do I pass these values in as `AttributeValue`'s so that I can write them to DDB? I already have two Java classes called `IceCreamFlavorTried` and `IceCreamFlavorsTried`, which look like this:

```
IceCreamFlavorTried {
  String flavor;
  Integer rating;
  Long lastTimeFlavorHasBeenTried; //Long represents Millis timestamp
  Integer outdoorTemperatureWhenLastTried;
}

IceCreamFlavorsTried {
  List<IceCreamFlavorTried> iceCreamFlavorsTried;
}
```

I am assuming that `IceCreamFlavorTried` (for a single flavor) will end up being a `Map` in DDB. So I am guessing, as far as DDB is concerned, we would be writing a list of maps to DDB?

Any help is appreciated. And if you have any clarifying questions, please do ask!